# Excel 2010 Pivot Table - Convert Text into Data

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have 2 worksheets that I need to create 2 different pivot tables for.

**On the first worksheet** (Injuries) I need the data to be sorted by Department (FSD or Dist), which is marked by placing an "X" in the correct category.

I then need columns that quantify which type of injury it was, for example "Record Only", "Lost Time", etc. and know how many lost days there are for each department.

I'm stumped on how to change the marked categories into actual numerical data in the table.

**On the second table**, "Motor Vehicle Accidents", I again need the data sorted between department, which is marked with an "X".

I then need to know which type of accident it was, for example "Preventable" or "Parked".

[image]

[image]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Please post an image and read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: I've inserted a picture of each worksheet but I'm new to the site so it won't allow me to post them until I earn more points. I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Column that maps that for you. For example, for the first Sheet, you can make a column and put the following formula on the cell:

```
=IF(D46<>"";"FSD";"DST")
```

For the second, it will be the same principle:

```
=IF(G85<>"";"PREVENTABLE";IF(H85<>"";"NON PREVENTABLE;IF(I85<>"";"PARKED";"1-800 MOR")))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. Add these columns into the worksheets themselves? I cannot edit the main data or add anything extra. I'm an Excel beginner so I don't understand the IF formulas...

Comment: Well, you can use pivot tables to count or formulas. For the pivot table, you just drag the FSD and DIST fields to the "Values" box and configure them to "count of". You can learn more about pivot tables here: [link](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html). This will give you a count of the X's marked in the columns. I also recommend to take some time to study about excel formulas, they are very useful :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want to count the number of each type of injury and accident by department (FSD or Dist). If I place those within the "Values" box, it will only count the number of total marks in each category rather than giving me the data I want for each department. Any extra advice?

Comment: For what you are asking, put the FSD and DIST columns in the "Filter" box, that way, you can filter the ones marked with "X". Then, put the data you want to see in the "Values" box :)